# Are HTML encoded special characters required to end in a semicolon?

Tags: html, character-encoding, html-email

The correct encoding for [em-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em-dash#Em_dash) is supposedly `&#8212;`, however when the semi-colon is left off it still displays correctly in my browers (chrome and firefox).

Furthermore, I'm using [Litmus.com](http://litmus.com/) to test character encodings across several email clients. It turns out nearly all of them also ignore the required semicolon when displaying special characters with the exception of gmail (IE, chrome, and firefox).

So my question: Are encoded HTML special characters required to end in a semicolon? It seems like gmail is playing by the rules while everyone else ignores the required semi-colon.

Comment: When you ask "required", do you mean required by the spec or required by browsers?

Comment: @BoltClock I meant required by the spec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since HTML up to version 4.01 is SGML based it is possible to eliminate the final `;`, see [w3centities](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html#entities).

> Note. In SGML, it is possible to eliminate the final ";" after a character reference in some cases (e.g., at a line break or immediately before a tag). In other circumstances it may not be eliminated (e.g., in the middle of a word). We strongly suggest using the ";" in all cases to avoid problems with user agents that require this character to be present.

However, the [current HTML5 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/syntax.html#character-references) states that character references need to be terminated with a semicolon. In order to prepare your current sites for HTML5 I recommend you to end the references with a semicolon.

Comment: In addition, in XHTML, the semicolon is always required, by general XML rules.

Answer (score 5):

Browsers do their best to interpret your intentions and are somewhat forgiving. It's best to stick to the rules to ensure things work properly everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There have been several debates about the 'optional' semi-colon use-case. The best advice I can give you is to use it.

If the rule is using it causes **ALL** browsers to work and not using it causes **MOST** browsers to work, go with the **ALL**.

Plus, W3C states it here (though I can't find the full spec): http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do have to have an semi-colon at the end. However the browser does forgive most of the time and tries to interpret it. Here is an example where it might fail:

> this&ampthat will return `this&ampthat`  -- FAIL

while

> `this&amp;that` will return `this&that`   -- WORK